# Problem of Curly Brackets in my controller Php Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I want to call my function but when I call it I have a problem with curly Brackets at the end of my code and i have this error [Error SYMFONY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUI53.png) ( {} ) in my Controller.

I have no idea where to put them for my code to work. I have this problem when I add my function that allows me to retrieve the
history of the action. The mentioned function goes as this:

`$this->logHistory->addHistoryConnection($project->getId(), $user->getId(), 'Delete Local Suf', $sf_code);`

### Function Supp Suf

```
/**
 * @Route("/creation/suf/supp", name="suf_supp")
 */
public function suf(
    Request $request,
    ShapesRepository $shapesRepository
) {
    $params = $this->requestStack->getSession();
    $projet = $params->get('projet');

    $modules = $params->get('modules');
    $fonctionnalites = $params->get('fonctionnalites');

    $user = $this->getUser()->getUserEntity();
    $manager = $this->graceManager;
    $mapManager = $this->mapManager;

    $countElements = $mapManager->getCount();
    $shapes = $shapesRepository->findBy(array('projet' => $projet->getId()));

    $adresseWeb = $this->getParameter('adresse_web');
    $carto = $params->get('paramCarto');
    $centrage = $params->get('centrage');
    $cableColor = $params->get('cableColor');

    $sf_code = '';
    if ($request->get('suf') != '') {
        $sf_code = $request->get('suf');
    }

    $suf = $manager->getSuf($sf_code);

    $success = '';
    $error = '';
    $warning = '';

    if ($request->query->get('success')) {
        $success = $request->query->get('success');
    } elseif ($request->query->get('error')) {
        $error = $request->query->get('error');
    } elseif ($request->query->get('warning')) {
        $warning = $request->query->get('warning');
    }

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        if ($request->request->get('sf_code') != '') {
            $sf_code = $request->request->get('sf_code');
        }

        if ($request->get('val') != '') {
            $val = $request->get('val');
        }

        $dir = $this->getparameter('client_directory');
        $dossier = str_replace(' ', '_', $projet->getProjet());
        $dir = $dir . $dossier . '/documents/';

        $cable = $val[0];
        $chem = $val[1];

        $t_suf = $this->graceCreator->supprimeSuf($sf_code, $cable, $chem);

        if ($t_suf[0][0] == '00000') {
            $this->logHistorique->addHistoryConnection($projet->getId(), $user->getId(), 'Suppression Suf Local', $sf_code);


            // $creator->delDirObjet( $st_code, $dir );
            $data = new JsonResponse(array("success" => "create!"));
            return $data;
        } else {
            $data = new JsonResponse(array("error" => "Error : " . $t_suf));
            return $data;
        }
        return $this->render('Modifications/supSuf.html.twig', array(
        'user' => $user,
        'paramCarto' => $carto,
        'cableColor' => $cableColor,
        'suf' => $suf,
        'adresseWeb' => $adresseWeb,
        'centrage' => $centrage,
        'shapes' => $shapes,
        'projet' => $projet,
        'modules' => $modules,
        'fonctionnalites' => $fonctionnalites,
        'countElements' => $countElements
    ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Also please, add the error as `code` instead of an image. Glad I could help!. I'll change my comment to an answer so the question can be considered as solved. Accept it if it solved your issue.

Comment: and please cleanup this "code" it so redundant and unreadable... for example. 
$sf_code is initialized as '' you dont need that if. just use `$sf_code = $request->get('sf_code', '');` 4 lines saved. and you have this multiple times. in general why do you default to empty strings? use null thats what it is for. and its easier to test as for an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your only return statement is inside of an if condition.** If the code does not pass the condition, it has nothing to return. **The code must return something in all possible cases.** If you are not still used to these practices, an IDE might guide you until it becomes a routine. PHPStorm is my personal preference.

---

BTW, I recommend you to switch from the array() syntax to the more globally accepted [] although you must be in PHP 5.4 or higher.